# Pass a==b as parameters to uniform_real_distribution ok

Tags: c++, random, libstdc++

Is it ok to use `std::uniform_real_distribution` with `a==b`? This condition can be interpreted as no randomness.

In GNU c++ library:

```
explicit
param_type(_RealType __a = _RealType(0),
           _RealType __b = _RealType(1))
: _M_a(__a), _M_b(__b)
{
   _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_ASSERT(_M_a <= _M_b);
}
```

The assertion accepts `a==b` though it might require division by zero. Is this

- An extension to the standard?
- A clever design that works anyways?
- An error that happens to work on certain CPUs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant normative paragraph  [26.5.8.2.2, rand.dist.uni.real]/1 says:

> A `uniform_real_distribution` random number distribution produces random numbers *x*, *a* ≤ *x* < *b*, distributed according to the constant probability density function
>
> ```
> p(x | a, b) = 1/(b − a) .
> ```
>
> [*Note*: This implies that p(x | a, b) is undefined when `a == b`. — *end note*]

Note that *a* < *b* is a constraint on the distribution.

Interestingly, the constructor (paragraph 2) has a looser requirement:

> ```
> explicit uniform_real_distribution(RealType a = 0.0, RealType b = 1.0);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: a ≤ b [...]

This means that you may *construct* a distribution object with `a == b`, but the distribution that it describes is undefined. That is, you may not attempt to generate values with such a distribution object using those parameters (which may indeed incur a division by zero, or anything else).

See also [N3926](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3926.pdf) for an opinion why these two constraints are not inconsistent. The issue had originally been raised as [LWG 2168](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2168) and has been resolved by the addition of the quoted note in the first paragraph. The paper calls attention to the overload of `operator()` that takes different distribution parameters; the upshot is that the constraints only come into play when generating values, not when constructing the distribution object.

Comment: The note is not normative, and `p(x | a,b)` can be a Kronecker Delta mathematically. It doesn't need to be finite. (Loosely, a Kronecker Delta is a rectangle with width zero and area 1). I'm not convinced.

Comment: @MSalters: Even if you want to get pedantic, 1/0 is still undefined even in mathematics. The fact that constructions of functional analysis or measure theory allow you to deal with point measures does not change that very normative aspect of `1 / (b - a)`...